# Trouble with includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I need to build a query to select records by two criteria (two models): `Branch(id)` and `Plan(created_at)`

I tried following queries:

```
@branches = Branch.where(id: 2).includes(:plans).where("created_at > ?", 1.week.ago)
@branches = Branch.where(id: 2).includes(:plans).where(plans: { "created_at > ?", 1.week.ago })
@branches = Branch.includes(:plans).where(branches: { id: 2 }, plans: { "created_at > ?", 1.week.ago })
```

I have an error

> syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end ... "created_at >
>   ?", 1.week.ago })

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just from reading your code, the problem is with incorrect syntax of your `hash`:

```
{ "created_at > ?", 1.week.ago }
```

Which should be an array:

```
[ "created_at > ?", 1.week.ago ]
```

But for your use case, I think you need something like:

```
@branches = Branch.where(id: 2)
                  .joins(:plans)
                  .includes(:plans)
                  .where("plans.created_at > ?", 1.week.ago)
```

In order to be able to use a `Plan`'s column `created_at`, `includes` is not enough - in that case the error will be thrown of unknown `plans`. This is why you need to specify `joins` to properly build whole query.

Hope that helps!

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

`{ "created_at > ?", 1.week.ago }` isn't correct hash syntax, it should be in an array:

```
[ 'created_at > ?', 1.week.ago ]
```

Answer (score 0):

May this works for you,

```
Branch.includes(:plans).where(["id = ? and plans.created_at > ?", 2, 1.week.ago])
```